# Does EF 5 Beta 2 support table-valued parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Does EntityFramework 5 Beta 2 support table-valued parameters? I haven't seen anything about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't but you can vote for this feature on [Data UserVoice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015347-table-valued-parameters).